# Jquery nextUntil and row cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a html table with the following structure:

```
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <td><img id="test_click" src=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

How can i hide all table rows between two  using jquery?

This code does not work as i suspected :(

```
$("#test_click").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().nextUntil('tr.header').find('tr').hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`nextUntill` already selects your `tr`s. No need to `.find` anything:

```
$("#test_click").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().nextUntil('tr.header').hide();  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nMBrw/